# How features are integrated in between Stack Exchange forums?

Tags: support, feature-request, stackexchange

Recently Stack Overflow introduced [dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395949/dark-mode-beta-help-us-root-out-low-contrast-and-un-converted-bits) preference option, but it isn't available here, at *Unix & Linux*.

How it works for it be provided at the other forums?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [How do I enable dark mode on other sites in the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345886), it is not yet available outside of Stack Overflow:

> Dark mode is currently in beta and only available on Stack Overflow. You cannot enable it anywhere else at this time.

Comment: It's worse than that. From [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/) announcing this: "For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network."